# Ordered $k$-covers of $[n]$

Tags: combinatorics

An ordered $k$-cover of $[n]$, for $k\in\mathbb{P}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, is a sequence $(A_1,\dots,A_k)$ of subsets of $[n]$ such that $A_1\cup\dots\cup A_k=[n]$. If $m(n,k)$ is the number of ordered $k$-covers of $[n]$, then is this formula (by the principle of inclusion and exclusion) correct?

$$m(n,k)=2^{n}-\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}j^{n}$$

I don't know how to simplify it further.... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where does the initial $2^n$ come from? I count $9$ ordered $2$-covers of $[2]$, your formula gives $8-2+4=10$.

Comment: If I let A be the set of all subsets of [n], then $|A|=2^{n}$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but just subsets of $[n]$ do not seem to relate to this problem. If you need to do inclusion-exclusion for finding $k$-covers, you could start with $k$-tuples of subsets of $[n]$, of which there are $2^{kn}$; that would seem a more natural starting term to me.

Comment: What's an ordered $k$-cover of $[n]$?

Comment: given $k\in\mathbb{P}$ an ordered k-tuple is a sequence (A1,A2,...,Ak) of subsets of [n] such that the union of of A1,...,Ak = [n]

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Marc, would you mind elaborating on your comment a little more please....

Comment: @Dome: The question has been modified beyond recognition (and comprehension) since I made the comment. If you want me to answer the question, I must roll back the question to its original form. If you want that, please say so.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen that would be great!

Comment: So I rolled back to the original question. For the case $n=k=2$ we are looking for pairs of subsets of $S=\{1,2\}$ whose union is the whole set. Writing $0$ for $\emptyset$, $i$ for $\{i\}$ when $i\in S$ and $3$ for $S$ itself, I find $(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)$ as solutions, $9$ in all. But your formula gives $2^2-\binom211^2+\binom222^2=4-2+4=6$ so it is certainly wrong (I don't know why I got $10$ before, but in any case it ain't $9$). And as for the second comment, the set of all subsets of $S$ does not arise directly in the problem, so $2^n$ is mysterious.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen okay, i guess what i'm having difficulties with is counting the actual k-covers... suppose S=[3], then S={0,1,2,3}. then its subsets are {0} {1}, {2}, {3}, {12}, {13}, {23}, {123}?

Answer (score 4):

Given Dome's comment of 09/17/13 I interpret the question as follows: We have to count the number of $k$-tuples $(A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_k)$ of subsets $A_i\subset[n]$ having the property $\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq k}A_i=[n]$.

This means that for each number $\ell\in[n]$ we can freely decide in which of the $A_i$, $\>1\leq i\leq k$, it shall occur, under the sole condition that it occurs in at least one of the $A_i$. In other words: We have to select for each $\ell\in[n]$ a nonempty subset $J_\ell\subset[k]$. When these sets $J_\ell$ have been selected put
$$A_i:=\bigl\{\ell\in[n]\ \bigm|\ i\in J_\ell\bigr\}\qquad(1\leq i\leq k)\ .$$
There are $2^k-1$ nonempty subsets of $[k]$, and we can select  one of them independently for each $\ell\in[n]$. Therefore the total number $N$ of admissible $k$-tuples $(A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_k)$ is given by
$$N=\left(2^k-1\right)^n\ .$$

Comment: Is there a way to do it by the principle of inclusion and exclusion?

Comment: Maybe someone will produce a solution using this principle.

Answer (score 1):

This is an argument using Inclusion-Exclusion, but Christian Blatter's solution is much simpler:

Let S be the set of all ordered selections of k subsets of $[n]$, and let $E_{i}$ be the set of selections which do not have the element i in the union of the subsets, for $1\le i\le n$.

Then $\displaystyle \vert \overline{E_{1}}\cap\cdots\cap\overline{E_{n}}\vert=\vert S\vert-\sum_{i}\vert E_{i}\vert+\sum_{i<j}\vert E_{i}\cap E_{j}\vert-\cdots $

$\displaystyle\;\;\;\;\;=2^{nk}-\binom{n}{1}2^{(n-1)k}+\binom{n}{2}2^{(n-2)k}-\binom{n}{3}2^{(n-3)k}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-1}2^k+(-1)^n$

$\displaystyle\;\;\;\;\;=x^n-\binom{n}{1}x^{n-1}+\binom{n}{2}x^{n-2}-\binom{n}{3}x^{n-3}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-1}x+(-1)^n$

$\displaystyle\;\;\;\;\;=(x-1)^n=(2^k-1)^n$,  using $x=2^k$.